# Response does not contain any data

Tags: spring, rest

I have developed a Restful web service using spring 3. When i invoke the service locally using chrome's Advance Rest Client, I am getting the response along with the response body but when i am trying to invoke i from LINUX server I am getting

Status

```
200 OK 
Show explanation Loading time: 545
```

Request headers:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: application/xml 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response headers:

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Date: Fri, 11 Oct 2013 07:16:21 GMT 
Content-Length: 0 
Via: 1.1 pr-inet-016.emea.isn.corpintra.net:3128 (Cisco-IronPort-WSA/7.5.0-833), 1.1 smtcig0021.in623.corpintra.net:3128 (Cisco-IronPort-WSA/7.5.0-833) 
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

and Response does not contain any data.

I cannot find any error on the tomcat server logs, The sane code when executed locally gives me an xml response

Comment: Is this getting called from Ajax?

Comment: Can you post request/response from locally invoked Advance Rest Client